# Guards and concatiating to lists in an anonymous function

Tags: haskell, lambda, anonymous-function, higher-order-functions

I am trying to wrap my head around the syntax of Haskell.

This problem is very simple to solve logically. I have to break up a list of positive and negative integers and group them such that

[1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,1,2,3] becomes [[1,2,3],[-1,-2,-3], [1,2,3]]

I would like to use a higher order function, foldr to be able to do that with an anonymous function taking in two arguements.

This is what I have so far.

```
split = foldr (\ x y -> if (x > 0) 
                        then if (head (head y)) < 0
                            then [x] : y
                            else x : head y --error here
                        else if (x < 0) 
                        then if (head (head y)) > 0
                            then [x] : y
                            else x : head y
                        else y
                )
                [[]]
```

this is the error i get

```
 Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `x'
    In the expression: x : head y
    In the expression:
      if (head (head y)) < 0 then [x] : y else x : head y
```

I have two questions.

1) Why am I getting a type error at line 7?

Am I not concatenation an integer (x) to a list of integers (head y)

2) How do you write the conditions out using guards? I tried doing it but I kept getting `parsing error at '|'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply missing to keep `tail y`. In

```
foldr (\ x y -> if (x > 0) 
                    then if (head (head y)) < 0
                        then [x] : y
                        else x : head y
```

you have `x :: (Num a, Ord a) => a`, `y :: (Num a, Ord a) => [[a]]`, and `head y :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a]`.

So forgetting the `tail y` shaves off one layer of `[]`. the `else` branch should be

```
else (x:head y) : tail y
```

in both branches of the outer `if`.

But, your function has two semantic problems after that.

First, you don't treat the case that `head y` is empty, that will cause an exception when the end of the list is reached, and second, it doesn't work on infinite lists, since the combinator function doesn't construct anything of the result before its second argument is known. If the latter is a problem, you can find a sufficiently lazy combinator function [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12838914/1011995).

Comment: Ah. Thank you so much! Is it correct to say that by having 'x: head y', i will not be "returning" in a sense a list of a list, but only a list?

Answer (score 2):

1. A function can have only one concrete return type and `[x] : y` is a different type from `x : head y`.
2. It's probably easier to write it with `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`:

   ```
   split l = split' (if head l > 0 then (>) else (<)) l 
     where split' op [] = []
           split' op l = takeWhile (`op` 0) l : split (dropWhile (`op` 0) l)
   ```